# Inserting a value into database having a BIGINT data type column

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtextfield

What would you recommend? I have this problem that there's a jTextField for a cellphone number. Now I want it to insert on my database. The column name is Contact #.

for example `INSERT INTO tblInfo(Contact #) VALUES(12345678901)`

would I say `INSERT INTO tblInfo VALUES(Integer.parseInt(jTextField.getText()))` ?

totally not. Because Integer are exclusive only for a few digits for a BIGINT data type database column.

What's the alternate Java Class other than Integer and of course having a method that casts the String of jTextField  that suits into BIGINT datatype in SQL. Thank you for responding.

Comment: _Why_ are you storing phone numbers as BIGINT to begin with???

Comment: The ease of manipulating it than making it VARCHAR. And of course BIGINT data type stores many digits. and in addition this may help me educate as a student. Curiosity you know.

Comment: What ease? Are you adding phone numbers? Are you multiplicating them?

Comment: no multiplication. Just inserting it. Because in our country phone numbers are 11 digits long. The simple Integer cant handle that long. BIGINT does. So i used BIGINT. But if ever I haven't found any solution or any alternates. I will Alter the column and make it as VARCHAR as my last resort.

Comment: (and in addition this may help me educate as a student. Curiosity you know.) - then to use 1. PreparedStatement, 2. JFormattedTextField with number instance, formatter

Comment: I use Statement class not PreparedStatement. number 2 is quite hard to comprehend. Perhaps I'll make the column VARCHAR. Thanks